# Display Html content when flash stop

Tags: jquery, flash-cs5, flash

i have html page in which i have use flash to display color shade from left side to mid of the page. when flash stop i am trying to float html content on flash.is that possible to display html when flash finish his work please suggest something.

```
  <div id="flashContent">
   <div class="branding"><h1>Test</h1></div>
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="resizing3" align="middle" >

            <param name="movie" value="resizing3.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="scale" value="noborder" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="resizing3.swf" width="100%" height="100%"><p>Test</p>
                <param name="movie" value="resizing3.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="scale" value="noborder" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a Js function in your AS code like this:

```
public function myFlashFunction():void {
   ExternalInterface.call("myJavascriptFunction", "argument");  
}
```

JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myJavascriptFunction(param) {
    alert(param);
}
</script>
```

You can find a complete exemple here : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-communicate-between-flash-and-javascript--active-3370